# Android SQLite null pointer exception on opening database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having trouble executing my SQLite app on adroid. For testing purpose I made it as simple as possible. A query that adds data into the database, and when the user clicks on "View Schedule" button, all the data in the DB should be displayed as a TOAST message. 
"The MySQLitehelper.java" file has all the Database related code and the "SelectOptions.java" has the code that has the button to "View Schedule". All the right imports have been added hence I have omitted them here.

On Tracing LogCat, I see that there is a null pointer exception when you call the helper.open() method of MySQLitehelper class. I tried printing statements to track it and figured out that the program shuts down the following lines:

```
  public MySQLitehelper open() throws SQLException
 {
    System.out.println("Inside open function");
     db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();  // even tried helper.getWritableDatabase()
    return this;
 }
```

and stops when the line

```
 db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

is encountered.
Here is my code:

/* --------------MySQLitehelper.java  code -----------------*/

```
public class MySQLitehelper {

//public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "comments";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "GWid";
  public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
  public static final String COLUMN_LOCATION = "location";
  public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time";

  public static final String TABLE_NAME = "UPDTable";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UPDdb";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  private final Context context;


  // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME +
                                " (" +COLUMN_ID+ " VARCHAR," + COLUMN_DATE + "VARCHAR," +
                                COLUMN_LOCATION+" VARCHAR," +COLUMN_TIME +" VARCHAR);";

  private static final String DATABASE_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " +TABLE_NAME +
                                                " Values ('47688507','DEC-07-2012','MARVIN 203','20:00');";


  DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
  SQLiteDatabase db;

 public MySQLitehelper(Context ctx)
  {
      this.context = ctx;
  }

 private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

     public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
     {
         super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION);
     }

 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);            //execute create table
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_INSERT);            //execute insert query

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w(MySQLitehelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}


// open the DB
 public MySQLitehelper open() throws SQLException
 {
    System.out.println("Inside open function");
     db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
 }

 public void close()
 {
     dbhelper.close();
 }


public Cursor getAllrows()      //function to get all rows in the DB. Testing initially.
{
    //SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur=db.query(TABLE_NAME,new String []{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_DATE,
            COLUMN_LOCATION,COLUMN_TIME},null,null,null,null, null);

     return cur;
}

  }
```

/*------------- SelectOptions.java  class ------------------*/

```
    public class SelectOptions extends Activity {

Button btnView, btnDrop, btnLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_options);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    btnView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnViewShift);
    btnDrop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDropShift);
    btnLocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnViewLocation);


    final MySQLitehelper helper = new MySQLitehelper(this);


    btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            helper.open();
            Cursor c = helper.getAllrows();
              if (c.moveToFirst()) {
             do {

                 System.out.println("In Do while");
                 DisplayRecord(c); 

             } while (c.moveToNext());
          }
            helper.close(); 
            System.out.println("Out of Do");



        }  
    });


}

public void DisplayRecord(Cursor c)
{
    System.out.println("In side toast display function");
    Toast.makeText(this, "id: "+c.getString(0)+"\n"+
            "Date: "+c.getString(1)+"\n"+
            "Location: "+c.getString(2)+"\n"+
            "Time: "+c.getString(3), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


    }
```

**LogCat**

```
11-29 06:18:01.393: I/System.out(8162): Inside open function
11-29 06:18:01.453: E/SQLiteLog(8162): (1) no such column: date
11-29 06:18:01.453: D/AndroidRuntime(8162): Shutting down VM
11-29 06:18:01.463: W/dalvikvm(8162): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
11-29 06:18:01.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8162): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 06:18:01.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8162): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: date (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT GWid, date, location, time FROM UPDTable
11-29 06:18:01.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-29 06:18:01.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
11-29 06:18:01.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
11-29 06:18:01.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
11-29 06:18:01.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
11-29 06:18:01.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
11-29 06:18:01.503: E/AndroidRuntime(8162):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
```

Comment: Do you have the write on external media permission?

Comment: @rekire: I am sorry, but I don't know what it means. I have been following tutorials that don't need explicit permission to SQLite database. Apologize, but I am a newbie to android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the line below . The format of the 20:00 parameter is invalid. Should be a string "20:00" or valid integer or float - 20.0

```
 enter code here`private static final String DATABASE_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " +
      TABLE_NAME +    " Values ('47688507','DEC-07-2012','MARVIN 203',20:00);";
```

Comment: I rectified that. I have updated the post with the corrections. Still same problem. I have updated the error logs. "Application closed down unexpectedly"

Comment: You might need to delete the database and create it again. There seems to be an existing database with a different column name. In your code you create a new DB only if one doesnt exist. It probably DOES exist, but column name has been changed

Comment: So what if I remove the IF NOT EXISTS clause when I created the query ? would that work ? or should i redesign the Database ?

Comment: Quickest fix is to change the version number or name of the database. See if it works

Comment: YOu shouldnt remove the IF NOT EXISTS clause. This is correct way to create a database in a simple app where the database schema wont change

Comment: I tried bothways. Changing the version number and the DATABASE_NAME string. No change. still logCat has the same error log: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _dateGW (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT GWid, _dateGW, location, time FROM UPDTable
11-29 06:50:13.233: E/AndroidRuntime(8553):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)

Should I even change the TABLE_NAME ?

Comment: YOu've changed your question so that I cant see whats going on any more. I think that your SELECT statement uses different column names to how you originally created your DB. You can change your select to the format "Select * from TABLE_NAME" to get all columns

Comment: YEs, I did change the select query and its working. Thanks a lot. All the suggested answers including this one were missing which forced my application to shut down. Thanks man

Comment: Whew...!!!! Finally man. Stuck over this from th epast 2 days. could go ahead. Thanks for all your help. I learnt a lot more now.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't initialized your dbhelper instance

write this statement into your MySQLitehelper() constructor

```
dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
```

complete code

```
public MySQLitehelper(Context ctx)
{
      this.context = ctx;
    dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
}
```

**Edited**

your insert query is wrong at last value 20:00 should be as '20:00'

```
private static final String DATABASE_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " +TABLE_NAME +
                                                " Values ('47688507','DEC-07-2012','MARVIN 203','20:00');";
```

Comment: Pratik, I tried adding the line you mentioned. Still same effect. Here is my logcat output after adding the line suggested by Pratik.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I rectified the mistake. But still doesn't solve me problem. Now the logcat has the following error logs: (check updated post)

Comment: change the date to _date as the date is data type so can't use this as column name

Comment: Do you suggest that I use COLUMNDATE instead of COLUMN_DATE ?

Comment: no i am suggesting you to change its value from "date" to "_date" or any thing else you want

Comment: I edited and even tried using _date instead date in the line   public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "_date";
But still app closes down unexpectedly.
Log entry: no such column: _date

Comment: change the database version

Answer (score 1):

you are getting the NULLPointer Exception because you haven't instantiate the **dbHelper** object in MySQLitehelper constructor.